# Evaluating foundations of Geometry

Tags: geometry

$VX$ is bisected by $XL$ and $XZ$ at $X$ creating three angles. If $\angle{VXY}=6x-14$ and $\angle{YXZ} = 2x+5$ and $\angle{WXZ=2x-1}$ find the degree measures of $\angle{VXY}$,$\angle{YXZ}$,and $\angle{WXZ}$

Comment: VX is, presumably, a line segment with endpoints V and X. "Bisected" means "cut in half". How can a line segment ending at X be cut in half by XL, another line segment going through X? And what does this have to do with "foundations of Geometry"?

Comment: To add to @Gerry's comment, the point $Y$ is not defined in the problem.